# How to stop TypeScript compiler from reporting compilation errors in symlinked modules

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, symlink, monorepo, pnpm

I have a monorepo controlled by rush.js with PNPM as a package manager.

I used to have all shared modules to be precompiled into `cjs`, `esm`, `dts` targets. But this approach has some flaws, so I decided to keep them as untouched sources, and set their main entry in `package.json` to be `"main": "./src/index.ts|x"`.
At the same time, I used `react-app-rewired` to tell Webpack to compile only those symlinked libraries from `node_modules` using babel and everything works perfectly. Jest is happy too.

The problem that I've got tho, is that when I run `tsc` for some reason compiler goes deep into the symlinked local packages and reports A LOT of issues (even tho they are compiling without any issues if you run their `tsc`).

`TSForkWebpackPlugin` reported similar issues for `create-react-app` but I ignored them using `reportFiles` config option using `react-app-rewired` and thought it was some sort of bug on plugin site, but it seems it's not.

I added all sorts of glob patterns to `exclude` like `**/node_modules/@namespace/**` and `node_modules/@namespace/**` and `node_modules/@namespace` none of those worked.
`"skipLibCheck": true` is there too.

My `tsconfig.json` for reference

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this problem, for now, is to make `tsc` think that symlinked projects are compiled libraries by adding `"types": "./types/index.d.ts"` or similar and emit declarations for real. Then, I assume since he thinks it's a library `skipLibCheck` starts to work and you're not getting issues anymore.

Surely it's not super optimal, but since we've been getting TS compiled to `cjs` and `esm` using Babel, we're saving a lot of time now anyway, while also having watch mode and other stuff from CRA multipackage wide. Before rebuild was required after each change for each local package which is not incremental e.g. long and inconvenient on many levels.

Any questions about details of implementation, please, ask me.